# Is there any word wrap function in teradata fastexport?

Tags: teradata, fastexport

In the column there is data with text, blank spaces and tabs. Using the fastexport utility to import data but it only gets the first line in the column and remaining text is not exported. 
**{Sample in table: the 3rd row with blank lines and tabs}**

2014-03-20 10:45:11,192303,caller/customer name: XXXX XXXX
cust. name:XXXXX

device:abc 4

cb#:n/a

issue:cannot connect to bluetooth devices but can pair to car

resolve:unwilling to do master reset 

**{Fastexport using  trim( BOTH '09'xc from col) but did not work}**


**{Output file: 3rd row data is cut off}**

2014-03-20 10:45:11,192303,caller/customer name: XXXX XXXX

Comment: It's a bit confusing: *Using the fastexport utility to import*, export or import? Hex 09 is a tab, but you need to remove linebreaks. Try `oTranslate` instead of `Trim`: `oTRANSLATE(col, '0A0D'xc, '  ')`

Comment: Using for fast export. oTranslate is removing lines from the column value is it contains special charaters. For e.g. in table:cust. name:xxxxx 


device:note 4


cb#:n/a

issue:cannot connect to bluetooth devices but can pair to car 
#id_56321
 #

resolve:unwilling to do master reset will be taking all stuff into store for help if defective replace within buyers remorse.<br> The output is shown as: cust. name:xxxxx device:note 4 cb

Comment: This oTranslate doesn't remove lines only line breaks. Can you show the export script?